# ENOENT error in Heroku deployment when typing in or redirecting to any route other than index

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, routes

I have read the other threads regarding Heroku's ENOENT error but they are having problems with loading their applications alltogether, I can load every page in my SPA but I can't type in any URL or redirect.

I have a monorepo project with this structure (I've used Brad Traversy's [Proshop](https://github.com/bradtraversy/proshop_mern) project as a template but I had to downgrade to Node.js 8.11.2 and switched the backend from ES Modules to the regular "require" syntax. ):

```
my-app/ 
├─ frontend/ 
├─ ├─ node_modules/ 
│  ├─ App.js 
├─ backend/ 
├─ ├─ node_modules/ 
│  ├─ server.js 
├─ .gitignore 
├─ package.json 
├─ README.md
```

This is how express is serving the routes:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../frontend/build')))

  app.get('*', (req, res) =>
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend', 'build', 'index.html'))
  )
} else {
  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('API is running....')
  })
}
```

My app functions without any problems in development environment but when deployed to Heroku, the index route works and SPA routes ( handled by `react-router-dom` ) work but if a user types any URL or any redirects happen I get this error:

```
  "message": "ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/backend/frontend/build/index.html'",
  "stack": null
```

What could be the most probable cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question on [r/Heroku](https://www.reddit.com/r/Heroku) and [u/jwsjr13](https://www.reddit.com/user/jwsjr13/) kindly answered it. The problem was basically related to how `__dirname` resolves itself.

[Link to the answer.](https://www.reddit.com/r/Heroku/comments/p175dl/enoent_error_in_heroku_deployment_when_typing_in/h8daif1?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

Direct quote:

> https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_resolve_paths
>
> > If no path segments are passed, path.resolve() will return the
> > absolute path of the current working directory.
>
> So it seemed to have been a relative path issue. __dirname is a global
> variable that must emerged with Node 8.
>
> The reason your development environment works, but production didn’t
> is this:
>
> In dev, you probably used a NPM package called concurrently to run two
> processes: one development version of react with an api proxy to the
> second process: your node server. They would run in two different
> ports and your API requests from your react app would proxy to your
> express server.
>
> On prod, react actually gets compiled to HTML/CSS/JS and is placed
> into the `frontend/build/` directory. Now your app runs on one
> process with the server throwing up the compiled React app for any
> request that isn’t caught by the API routes above.